# AppEngine Google Cloud Endpoint - discovery not found

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am quite new to Python and Google AppEngine, but have had around 7 years of programming experience. I am also new to StackOverflow.

I've been trying to set up a simple Google Cloud Endpoint API for my personal project, and have finished and uploaded the finished app to Google App Engine.

Here are my Endpoint API settings:

```
@endpoints.api(name='puzzle', version='v1', description='Puzzle Engine API')
```

And methods:

```
@endpoints.method(
        PuzzleMessage, PuzzleMessage,
        name='puzzle.generate',
        http_method='GET',
        path='generate'
    )

@endpoints.method(
        PuzzleMessage, PuzzleMessage,
        name='puzzle.solve',
        http_method='GET',
        path='solve'
    )
```

My app.yaml looks like:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/api/.*
  script: services.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

And finally services.py reads:

```
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints
from api import puzzle_api

application = endpoints.api_server([
                               puzzle_api.PuzzleAPI
                           ], restricted=False)
```

Now, the problem is that when I try to reach https://*my-app-name*.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis, all I see is

> Not Found

Also, when I hit the API Explorer at https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://*my-app-name*.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/, the list of Services is empty, and in the JavaScript console, I see a 404 error over https://*my-app-name*.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis.

Hitting these URLs on local test server gives quite different errors. When I try to reach the API Discovery on local test server at localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis, I get

> {"error": {"message": "BackendService.getApiConfigs Error"}}

instead of "Not Found". Hitting the Explorer at https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?base=http://localhost:8080/_ah/api#p/ would now show 500 error instead of 404 in the JavaScript console as well.

I've been trying to solve this by doing many Google Searches and trying many things out, but I just cannot seem to be able to proceed any further. I would very much appreciate any help I can get from this community of professionals.

Thanks.

Comment: You can (and should!) edit your question if you have new information to add. It'll make your question clearer and attract the attention of those who might answer it.

Comment: Thank you @MartinAtkins. I will do so.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is an issue with the 1.7.6 SDK as well; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666157 for more info. Try reversing the order of your handlers in `app.yaml` and using the 1.7.5 SDK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/api_server

You need to do the following:

Change your app.yaml to:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: services.application

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

**Note**: The url should be `/_ah/spi/.*` not `/_ah/api/.*`. Change it, then you can access your api at `/_ah/api/explorer`.

Comment: Making it `/_ah/spi/.*` is not needed in the new v2 version, right? How can we do this in new version?

Answer (score 2):

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app

# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/api/.*
  script: services.application
```

Try reversing the order of these handlers. It's typically good practice to always put the most general URL-matchers at the end of the list, lest they catch something that was meant to go to a more specific handler.

Comment: Thank you. I just have tried this after reading your answer, but unfortunately this did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change into **app.yaml**

```
# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: services.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest 
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```