# how do I point my android app to my online apengine endpoint

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-eclipse-plugin

I have created an app-engine connected android project. Presently I have deployed my backend (endpoint api) to app-engine. Now I want to point the android app (apk) to the online server/api. How do I do that?

Basically, is the following all I have to do?

```
protected static final boolean LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN = false;
```

When the line above is all I do, I get the exception

```
Exception received from server at https://1.myapi.appspot.com/_ah/api/
java.io.IOException: Hostname '1.myapi.appspot.com' was not verified
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.verifySecureSocketHostname(HttpConnection.java:224)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:446)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:281)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:78)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:980)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
```

Why is there a `1` preceding my app-id is that normal? Is that the problem? Where would I fix it? Again my project is entirely generated using GEP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number **1** just comes from the version number of your API, so it shouldn't be the problem...

Anyway, what App Engine SDK are you using? The **SDK 1.7.6** introduced some bugs in the generation of the endpoint client libraries using GPE that were not present in previous version, but they're solved with the new version **SDK 1.7.7**.

See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666157/why-is-my-api-not-showing-up-on-deployment) for further info about this *strange 1*, and the bug I was talking about.

Comment: +1 for trying to help. As it turns out @KonsolLabapen is correct. But then how do I get the emulator to work with my deployed endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Using process of elimination, my guess is you are trying to use an emulator to access your deployed endpoint. Using `LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN = false` should be all you need to do. Try running the apk on a real device and see. This is my guess based on your post and error log.

Comment: +1. You are correct. But then how do I get the emulator to work with my deployed endpoint?