# Getting android emulator to talk to online endpoint

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-eclipse-plugin

Ref to [how do I point my android app to my online apengine endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121987/how-do-i-point-my-android-app-to-my-online-apengine-endpoint) for background info.

I have deployed my app-engine endpoint. And now I would like to have my emulator talk to it. Does anyone know how to do that? Everything works fine on localhost. But when I switch to the deployed backend, I get an exception.

Comment: It's in the link provided, which is also a stackoverflow post.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking in this question versus the other question (which is marked as answered). Please provide the relevant details to your current question in this post.

Comment: In the other question I didn't know whether there was a difference between an emulator or a real device, given the context. The response to that question clarified that a real device would work. And since I made no distinction in the post, I thought it unfair to edit the post to specify emulator. So instead I am asking here specifically how to get an emulator to communicate to my deployed backend. The fact is I don't have enough device to test my app. So knowing how to get the emulator connected would be huge help. I also imagine others might wish the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using the emulator to talk to a deployed Endpoint should be nearly identical to using a real device. If you have an APK that works on a real device, choosing an emulator target when running should produce identical results.

The *one major caveat* to this is if you are using Google Play Services (a requirement of auth), which as of this posting, does not work on an emulated device. For testing authenticated APIs, you must use a physical device.