# GAE api endpoints are not getting created after deployment

Tags: google-app-engine

My application is deployed successfully using eclipse plugin. But endpoints are not visible in the apiexplorer. https://['my_app_name'].appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer.
Most probably these endpoints are not getting created. I tried using restclient plugin in Mozilla. It didn't work.( But It worked yday )
This service is really flickering. Are you guys facing the same issue ? It seems, the service is down.

Comment: Now I'm getting the following msg. "https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=[my_app_name]&version=1&
404 Not Found". It is really very frustrating. Developers should be notified if the server is down.

Comment: can u plz let me know why u r voting it down ?
When I had asked this qts, that time the service was down. I came to know about it from the following post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of trouble with Google Cloud Endpoints lately, but right now are working for me at least, and have been working properly for the last days, after a long downtime commented [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158013/error-generating-google-cloud-endpoint-client-libraries).

After deploying your app to APP Engine, you can check if the endpoints are being loaded correctly. You have to go to GAE Admin console, and go to Main > Logs. A little after deloyment you shoud see a request like this:

```
/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs 200
```

If you're not getting `200` response code, something is going wrong... Check the message and post it...

For more info, check the answer of [@bossylobster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068170/bossylobster) to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047744/gae-cloud-endpoints-api-not-updating-after-deploy).

By the way, there was an issue with GAE SDK 1.7.6, as commented [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666157/why-is-my-api-not-showing-up-on-deployment/15947022#15947022), that made endpoints not to be shown on deployment, but it's been fixed with SDK 1.7.7.